# Page not appearing under its Parent

Tags: pages

If I add a page with the name 'Bottle Project' and give it the parent 'Other Projects', the page appears at http://richardclunan.com/other-projects/bottle-project -- so that looks right.

...but if I mouse over the menu item 'Other projects' at http://richardclunan.com , the item 'Bottle Project' doesn't appear. And if I click on 'Other projects', then it doesn't appear either.

How can I make it so users can navigate to 'Bottle Project' from the menus on my site -- specifically that 'Bottle Project' appears under the menu item 'Other projects'...?

Comment: This is a *user-support* question, that would be better directed at the [wordpress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to appearance->Menus, you should be able to fully customize your menu, assuming your theme is even decent.

Comment: thanks m0. i'm using the latest default theme (twentyeleven?), with some modifications. In appearance>menus I can add the page so it appears in the main list, but I don't want it in the main list -- i want it under one of the main menu items...

Comment: i see now -- i positioned it wrong. got it. thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as solved.

Comment: hello I had the same problem, my sub menu item doesnt show up for the Parent page ? I can do it from Menu settings, but why doesnt it work from Page Attribute ? After I set a Parent page (published) for A page, it doesnt show up in Menus.